# Isolate UITableViewCell from UITableView by creating OVERLAY over another cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, overlay

I want to isolate selected UITableViewCell, by creating an overlay over another, not selected rows. Maybe someone tried to implement such behaviour? What is good practice to implement this? It still should be possible to scroll and handle events on selected row. We can unselect row by tapping on overlay.

[image: Overlay of UITableViewCell]

Comment: Show us what you have tried to achieve this and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I tried to add OverlayView to UITableWrapperView, but I dont like this solution, because I need always bring selected cell to front. And if after scrolling cell is recreated it shows up under overlay. So maybe there is better solution?